# how to return a value to the controller from a re-usable view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Specific question based on my implementation is:

Question:

- have a UIViewController which has a some views within it (configured in an XIB file)
- when something occurs in one of the controls on the screen here (i.e. in one of the views), how can I update a UIViewController parameter at the same time?

Background:

- In my case I have a colorPickerController, and within this there are some subview which the user interacts with the select the color
- when the user is dragging the mouse over one of the subviews, one of the other others is updated with the color
- what I'm not sure of is how to also keep the main colorPickerController parameter updated with the latest color that is being selected
- hence the question how to update/access a controller's parameter from within one of the views within a controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subview the user drags mouse (or finger?) over can be considered as some kind of a control, so you would just use target/action in that case. or may be a delegation. that way you would keep this subview and viewcontroller loosely coupled, and that would also allow you to reuse that same class (which the subview is instance of) in other places. so, in case of delegation:

1. define a protocol:

   @protocol ColorPickerViewDelegate

   - (void)colorPickerView:(ColorPickerView *)cpView didUpdateWithColor:(UIColor *)newColor;
     @end
2. add property `@property(nonatomic, assign) id<ColorPickerViewDelegate> didUpdateDelegate;` to color picking UIView subclass.
3. Make your viewcontroller adopt the above protocol and define the method from that protocol in viewcontroller's implementation section.
4. When creating a color picking subview, set your viewcontroller as that subview's didUpdateDelegate.
5. make calls to didUpdateDelegate at appropriate times in your color picking view touch-handling logic: `[didUpdateDelegate colorPickerView:self didUpdateWithColor:someNewColor];`

hope that's what you want

Comment: thanks.  So delegates avoids you having to understand the hierachy then, and kind of provides a way to send a message from one part of a code to another part then?  So do you think this is better than the controller somehow passing a variable by reference into the subview (which the subview updates, and then the controller would see), although I guess the controller in this case still wouldn't know when it changes

Comment: sorry, what hierarchy are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no any ColorPickerController in iOS Control Library ? Is it custom controller ? Please specify so can answer accordingly.